# Empty rspec fails when I add this custom validation to my User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a user model, if I add this custom validation my empty rspec test fails:

```
validate :password_complexity 

def password_complexity
    if !password.blank?
        errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") if password.match(/[A-Z]/)
    end
end
```

Rspec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

end
```

I run `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`  and I get:

> /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in
>   `raise_record_invalid': Validation failed: Password must contain a
>   upper case character, Password must contain a lower case character
>   (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in`
>   save!'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in
>   `save!'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in`
>   block in save!'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in
>   `block in with_transaction_returning_status'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in`
>   transaction'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in
>   `transaction'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`
>   with_transaction_returning_status'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in
>   `save!'   from
>   /Users/blank/dev/gitserver/myapp/myappweb/app/models/user.rb:74:in`
>   create_from_signup!'     from
>   /Users/blank/dev/gitserver/myapp/myappweb/app/services/account_service.rb:16:in
>   `block in create'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`
>   block in transaction'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in
>   `within_new_transaction'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`
>   transaction'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in
>   `transaction'     from
>   /Users/blank/dev/gitserver/myapp/myappweb/app/services/account_service.rb:11:in`
>   create'  from
>   /Users/blank/dev/gitserver/myapp/myappweb/db/seeds.rb:172:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in
>   `block in load'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`
>   load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in`
>   load_seed'   from
>   /Users/blank/dev/gitserver/myapp/myappweb/spec/spec_helper.rb:24:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:424:in`
>   instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:424:in
>   `instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:357:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in
>   `block in run_hooks_with'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in
>   `run_hooks_with'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1679:in`
>   with_suite_hooks'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:114:in
>   `block in run_specs'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in`
>   report'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in
>   `run_specs'   from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in`
>   invoke'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/rspec:22:in`load'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'  from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'    from
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `'

Why is this happening?  If I remove that custom validation, it runs fine.

My model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password 

  belongs_to :account

    validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :account_id }
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, on: :create

    validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 8, :maximum => 32, :allow_blank => false
    #validate :password_complexity 


    def password_complexity
        if !password.blank?
            errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") unless password.match(/[A-Z]/)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") if password.match(/[A-Z]/)
```

To

```
errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") unless password.match(/[A-Z]/)
```

Comment: I see this ```/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid': Validation failed: Password must contain a number (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Comment: Post your full model above please

Comment: When I comment out ```validate :password_complexity ``` the error goes away.

Comment: What happens if you use `password =~  /[A-Z]/` instead of match?